# R, function arguments, lapply

Tags: r, function

I am a newbie with R.

I stll struggle with functions. 
for example:

```
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")[,c(2,7,11,17,23)]
  names(data)[3] = "rate"
  data[, 3] = suppressWarnings( as.numeric(data[, 3]) )
  num<- 1
  data = data[!is.na(data$rate),]

  splited = split(data, data$State)
  ans = lapply(splited, function(x, num) {
    # Order by Deaths and then HospitalName
    x = x[order(x$rate, x$Hospital.Name),]

    # Return
    return (x$Hospital.Name[num])
  }, 1)

  #Return data.frame with format
  print( data.frame(hospital=unlist(ans), state=names(ans)) )
```

the above code works :)..however I don't get what `x` refers to in my function. does it refer to a row of the dataframe `splited`?

Comment: Can you show (a) some toy data and (b) code which produces what you want as an output from that data?  Is `x` supposed to be a list or a element of a list?

Comment: This code cannot be correct, `function(x,1) ...` would error with `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "function(x,1"`. Please paste the actual code.